# Google charts, timeofday starts at 8:00 and ends at 7:45

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I'm having some trouble with Google charts. I have a Google area chart:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
     data.addColumn('timeofday','time');
     data.addColumn('number','temp');
     data.addRows([
       [[8,0,0],7.875],
       [[8,15,0],7.9399996],
       [[8,30,0],8.1],
       [[8,45,0],8.160001],
       [[9,0,0],8.139999],
       // data every quarter of an hour
       [[7,15,0],9.26],
       [[7,30,0],9.26],
       [[7,45,0],9.18]
     ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Title',
      vAxis: {
        title: 'AvgTemp',
        titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'},
      }
      hAxis: {
        title: 'Time',
        titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'},
      }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

Now, when I load my page, the hAxis of the chart starts at 0:00 and ends at 24:00, and it destroys the chart. How can I make it so that the chart starts at 8:00 and ends at 7:45?

I've tried some things with view window but I can't seem to make it work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to use a datetime instead of a time of the day, this way you need to add a date and thats how the api knows which time comes first.

like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
     data.addColumn('datetime','time');
     data.addColumn('number','temp');
     data.addRows([

    [new Date(2012,11,3,8,0,0),7.875],
    [new Date(2012,11,3,8,15,0),7.9399996],
    [new Date(2012,11,3,8,30,0),8.1],
    [new Date(2012,11,3,8,45,0),8.160001],
    [new Date(2012,11,3,9,0,0),8.139999],
    //new data every quarter of an hour
    [new Date(2012,11,4,7,0,0),9.42],
    [new Date(2012,11,4,7,15,0),9.26],
    [new Date(2012,11,4,7,30,0),9.26],
    [new Date(2012,11,4,7,45,0),9.18]

     ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Title',
      vAxis: {  title: 'AvgTemp',
                titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'},

            },
      hAxis: {  title: 'Time',
                titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'},                 
            }

    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Let's say I *really* want to use the method of specifying the data in arrays instead of "new Date()", but with 'datetime' instead of 'timeofday'. Something like...

   data.addColumn('datetime','time');
   data.addColumn('number','temp');
   data.addRows([
      [[2015,11,20],7.875], ...

Has anyone gotten that to work?

Answer (score 0):

```
@oaklodge
producerCountDatatable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
// producerCountDatatable.addColumn('timeofday', 'Timestamp');
producerCountDatatable.addColumn('datetime', 'Time of day(Hours:Minutes)');
producerCountDatatable.addColumn('number', 'ProducerCount');
  for(var i = 0; i < hours.length; i++){
    //If you use timeofday          //producerCountDatatable.addRow([[parseInt(hours[i]),parseInt(minutes[i]),parseInt(seconds[i])],newProducerData[i]]);

//the following is for datetime 
producerCountDatatable.addRow([new Date(timeStampData[i]),newProducerData[i]]);
}
```

Comment: This answer would benefit from some commentary on why it solves the problem, instead of posting only the code.