# Google chart how to show display time statistic

Tags: time, charts, google-visualization

Hi I want to show in google chart two column. First with time (eg. 06:02) second with value (eg. 3).

I try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function drawVisualization() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DateFormat();

  // Declare columns
  data.addColumn('datetime', 'Time of Day');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Some Measurement');

  // Add data.
  data.addRows([
    [06:02,1],
    [07:02,1],
    [08:02,2],
    [12:02,15],
    [13:02,2],
    [14:02,1],
    [15:02,1],
    [16:02,1],
    [21:02,2],

  ]);

    // Create and draw the visualization.
    new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
        draw(data, {curveType: "function",
                    width: 500, height: 400,
                    vAxis: {maxValue: 10}}
            );
  }


  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

I try [google doc](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference?hl=pl&csw=1#dateformatter) but I must be doing something wrong...
It does'n work... Any idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type and format of data is wrong, should be `timeofday` and `[hour, min, sec, milli]`. It seems that the last one, milliseconds, could be omitted. Additionally, `DataTable` has to be created:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});

function drawVisualization() {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    // Declare columns
    data.addColumn('timeofday', 'Time of Day');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Some Measurement');

    // Add data.
    data.addRows([
        [[6, 2, 0], 1],
        [[7, 2, 0], 1],
        [[8, 2, 0], 2],
        [[12, 2, 0], 15],
        [[13, 2, 0], 2],
        [[14, 2, 0], 1],
        [[15, 2, 0], 1],
        [[16, 2, 0], 1],
        [[21, 2, 0], 2]
    ]);

    // Create and draw the visualization.
    new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
        draw(data, {
                curveType: "function",
                width: 500, height: 400,
                vAxis: {maxValue: 10}
            }
    );
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

</script>
```

If your measurements are over several days then you will have to change the chart according to explanation in [Google charts, timeofday starts at 8:00 and ends at 7:45](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219985/google-charts-timeofday-starts-at-800-and-ends-at-745)